# store.each function is giving me error

Tags: extjs4

Here is my task store and when I try to get its records using store.each it gives me TypeError: store.each is not a function

```
  store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                        model: 'Task',
                        folderSort: true,
                        sortInfo: {
                            field: "StartDate",
                            direction: "ASC"
                        },
                        root:
                                {
                                    text: '.',
                                    expanded: true,
                                    children: arrTasksData
                                }
                    });
```

I have a button on click of it I need to access store records.I am using below code to access records.

```
console.log(store.getCount()); //Prints undefined
store.each(function (record,id) {
 console.log(record.get("TaskName")); 
  });
```

The above code gives me error in console : TypeError: store.each is not a function

Though console.log(store) prints object
But console.log(store.getCount()) prints undefined.

Answer (score 0):

TreeStore uses nested structure for its data.
When you look at the API document from Sencha (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore), there's no getCount() method available for you to use.
**For dealing with Frameworks, API document is your best friend!**

So, your store.getCount() won't work.
You need to write your own function for counting leaf nodes for that matter.

I wrote a simple [Fiddle code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q27) for that purpose.
Please note that this hasn't been fully tested with various data.
This is just to give you some idea on what needs to be done.